# How to make alien spaceships collide with each other?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to teach myself Computer Programming using the book How to think like a computer programmer: learn Python 3. One of the exercise questions has me modify the free Python Game from PyGames called Aliens, see the full code from bithub [here](http://hg.pygame.org/pygame/src/7866ddf0ec0d/examples/aliens.py).

The goal is to have the alien ships collide with each other.

I'm actual not sure what bit of code to include, here is a modification i made to a copy of existing code:

```
        for alien in pygame.sprite.groupcollide(aliens, aliens, 1, 1).keys():
```

maybe obviously the alien sprite is in a constant state of colliding with itself. So the above code results in lots of explosions at the edges of the screen as the alien instantly collides with itself (at least this is what i imagine is happening)

The do route I went down and meet with limited success was to try to use direction of movement of the sprits distinguish between two different alien sprits (going right is positive and left is negative).

I worked myself in circles for some time and felt that i must be missing something obvious.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

youre right that the aliens are in a "constant state of colliding with themselves", so you need to check each alien against all the aliens excluding itself

well, this works:

```
    i = 0
    while i < len(aliens.sprites()): 
        check_alien = aliens.sprites()[i] #check alien 1.. alien 2.. etc

        aliens_except = pygame.sprite.Group() #here we create a new group
        n = 0 #without alien i, so we can use spritecollide while it doesnt collide
        for alien in aliens: #with itself
            if n != i: #exclude alien[i]
                aliens_except.add(alien)
            n += 1

        if not pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(check_alien, aliens_except):
            i += 1 #if theres no collision, move on to the next alien
        else:
            for alien in pygame.sprite.spritecollide(check_alien, aliens_except, 1):
                Explosion(alien) #remove all aliens that are colliding with check_alien
            for alien in pygame.sprite.spritecollide(check_alien, pygame.sprite.Group(check_alien), 1):
                Explosion(alien) #ugly way to remove check_alien
```

its not the most neat, intuitive or efficient piece of code, but gets the job done.
the comments should explain it sufficiently